# Unable to start gnome-session without root ?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gnome3, x-server

I have freshly installed arch linux according to the steps listed in arch linux wiki page, installed xorg and gnome. In my ~/.xinitrc file I have added the line  `exec gnome-session`.

Now, when I boot my system and login to tty1, as a normal user( not root) and type `startx` at the prompt the gnome session doesn't start and instead complains that the connection to the xserver is lost.

But when I log in as root or use `su` to issue command `startx` it starts without a problem. Can anyody help me with removing this problem ?

Comment: Hmmmm...firewall issues?  iptables issues?  File permission issues?

Comment: Do you have a file called `.xsession-errors` in your home directory? Or some other file that gets modified when you run `startx` (run `ls -Altr ~` to check)? If so, post the content of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the `.xinitrc` file in the user home directory. It seems you have the `.xinitrc` in the root directory and not the users home directory. to verify this run `ls -la` in the user home directory. If you see a `.xinitrc` file inspect it using a text editor to see if it has the required content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What a silly mistake on my part! My home directory had the .xinitrc file but didn't have the required `exec gnome-shell` line in it. Atleast your solution made me look into the .xinitrc file.